# Reducing geometry based on Geometry indices in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, geometry, raycasting

Title might be a result of an XYZ problem, my original intent is to save and load multiple selected regions on a model surface. The selection logic follows the example in Three-Mesh-BVH, (Example [here](https://gkjohnson.github.io/three-mesh-bvh/example/bundle/selection.html) and Source [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/is-it-possible-to-reduce-a-geometry-based-on-a-provided-index-array/58322/1#:%7E:text=https%3A//github.com/gkjohnson/three%2Dmesh%2Dbvh/blob/39b479b41b9ecfc473a9abc1ac300b3ce5c82f86/example/selection.js)), in which I can store the indices produced. The logic for reducing the visible geometry is as follows

```js
const originalIndex = mesh.geometry.index;
const highlightIndex = highlightMesh.geometry.index;
// update the highlight mesh
for ( let i = 0, l = indices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
   const i2 = originalIndex.getX( indices[ I ] );
   highlightIndex.setX( i, i2 );
}
highlightMesh.geometry.drawRange.count = indices.length;
highlightIndex.needsUpdate = true;
```

I want to do ray casts on a group containing the highlight meshes on mouse-move. However, this becomes slow as ray casts take a long time (even with one selection, maybe the boundsTree calculated for the original geometry is not being used?).